# Windows forms control tipo ventana de propiedades?

Tags: windows-forms

Alguien sabe si existe un control parecido a la ventana de propiedades propia de visual studio? Estoy tratando de replicar el control de la siguiente imagen pero no encuentro un control como este, espero puedan ayudarme:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la hay, se llama PropertyGrid y funciona muy bien, aqui te dejo código de ejemplo de la página de Microsoft :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

public class OptionsDialog : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid OptionsPropertyGrid;
    public OptionsDialog()
    {
        OptionsPropertyGrid = new PropertyGrid();
        OptionsPropertyGrid.Size = new Size(300, 250);

        this.Controls.Add(OptionsPropertyGrid);
        this.Text = "Options Dialog";
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new OptionsDialog());
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva como punto de partida.

Comment: Excelente, lo revisaré muchas gracias!